# How does the window.__shellInternal work in chrome scripting?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to understand some code on GitHub so that I can fork the repo and do something similar for another website, but I'm having a really hard time finding any documentation or questions online about how this code works. I'll share a link to the GitHub file and share the lines that are pertinent here.

#### What I understand:

The code is getting the current tab from Chrome on the first 4 lines so that the tab id can be used later.
If the specific tab is not found, it returns early.
Chrome scripting is invoked ([documentation on that here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/scripting)), and I learned about the MAIN world [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/access-variables-and-functions-defined-in-page-context-from-an-extension/9517879#9517879). It invokes the function declared by the key/value of `func`, which is `getMintApiKey` in this case.
And I understand the code below that

#### What I don't understand:

How is the `getMintApiKey` getting the API key from the tab? I've never seen `window.__shellInternal` and I'm having a hard time finding any documentation on it anywhere. Could someone please explain how this works?

#### GitHub link:

https://github.com/monarchmoney/mint-export-extension/blob/ef1d75874bb4e3669f15942cd0be3fd8f8b6fed3/src/pages/background/index.ts#L95-L126

#### Code:

```
const handleMintAuthentication = async (sendResponse: (args: unknown) => void) => {
  const [activeMintTab] = await chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    url: 'https://mint.intuit.com/*',
  });

  // No active Mint tab, return early
  if (!activeMintTab) {
    sendResponse({ success: false, error: ErrorCode.MintTabNotFound });
    return;
  }

  // Get the API key from the page
  const response = await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: activeMintTab.id },
    world: 'MAIN',
    func: getMintApiKey,
  });

  const [{ result: apiKey }] = response;

  if (apiKey) {
    await apiKeyStorage.set(apiKey);
    sendResponse({ success: true, key: apiKey });
  } else {
    sendResponse({ success: false, error: ErrorCode.MintApiKeyNotFound });
  }
};

function getMintApiKey() {
  return window.__shellInternal?.appExperience?.appApiKey;
}
```

I tried searching for documentation of the mysterious `window.__shellInternal` attribute. I was expecting if it were a common attribute, it would have been listed in the MDN documentation, or possibly the chrome documentation, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: I imagine that `__shellInternal` is something that the mint website defines that you're using the extension on

Comment: It's a global variable declared by the web site.

Comment: How can I inspect the website to find things like this? This is a whole new level that I don't have as much experience with

Comment: @Jet once you're on the page that you expect the extension to run on, open up the browser dev tools and go to the console tab. See if entering `window.__shellInternal` into the console gives anything.

Comment: Yep, I was able to `console.log(window)` and see that there at the bottom. Not sure why this was so overwhelming for me to understand...lol thank you!!